# ClipCursor is not working

Tags: windows, visual-c++, cursor, directx-11

I am working on a DX11 game, and I want to clip the cursor during fullscreen mode to the fullscreen window. I use this method

```
void MyClass::_SetupCursor( BOOL bFullscreen ) {
    // Clip cursor if requested
    if( bFullscreen ) {
        if(m_bShowCursorWhenFullscreen) {
            ShowCursor(m_bShowCursorWhenFullscreen);
        }
        if(m_bClipCursorWhenFullscreen) {
            // Confine cursor to full screen window
            RECT windowRect;
            GetWindowRect( m_hWnd, &windowRect );
            ClipCursor( &windowRect );
        }
    }
    else {
        ShowCursor( TRUE );
        ClipCursor( NULL );
    }
}
```

However, when I am in fullscreen mode with 2 monitors, I can still move the mouse over to the other monitor. With resolution set to 2048x1152 in fullscreen mode, I get the window rectangle as 1360x768, and that is what it gets clipped to. I confirm that it is clipped using GetClippedRect.

So I have two questions:

1) Why isn't the mouse getting clipped to the monitor my window is in?

2) Why is the window rectangle measured as 1360x768 when I know for a fact the monitor is 2048x1152, and I have the resolution set to 2048x1152?

Comment: Why are you trying to clip the cursor instead of just hiding it?

Comment: @CodyGray there is no point in hiding the cursor if it isn't clipped... I need the cursor to stay in the fullscreen window. Many games have this functionality, and yes I know they hide the windows cursor but they replace it with their own so it really isn't any different. I just haven't replaced the cursor yet.

Comment: Please avoid this function call entirely - you should really emulate you own cursor. The reason is that if your application quits uncleanly (segfault/exception/access violation/whatever) Windows will retain the clip bounds (at least <= Windows XP did). If you absolutely want the system cursor include a bounds check and use `SetCursorPosition` to restrain it instead.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I understand your concerns. My game is Win7 only, DX11 only, so there are no XP concerns. However, SetCursorPos is a viable alternative.

Comment: @Darkhydro just experiment - I only said that because it was the last time I ever used it; it might still be present in Vista\Win7. Make a simple app that crashes outright on a button click and constrain the cursor. Also, how does the user move your windows and what happens if they do. It's all to complicated.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson talking about the entire app is complicated - but this situation should be simple. The user can go fullscreen in one of the two monitors, and the cursor should be clipped in some manner to the window rectangle during fullscreen mode. I know from debugging that this method is being called every time the user goes fullscreen, and no other ClipCursor calls are being made.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I have found the source of the error, ClipCursor works just fine. The error comes from fullscreen toggling in my app; I already have a question open at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934374/why-is-d3d10sdklayers-dll-loaded-during-my-dx11-game if you would like to look at it. Thanks for the help on this anyways! I'll be deleting this question soon.

Comment: @Darkhydro don't delete it, there is some valuable information here. I don't know raw DX8+ too well unfortunately. Always leave the paper trail in case someone else encounters this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that for ClipCursor to work, you must have all your DX11 buffers and your window size correct. I found this out by running my application in fullscreen first, without toggling into it, and ClipCursor worked just fine, even with multiple monitors. For more information on when ClipCursor will fail, check out my other question on stackoverflow: [Why is D3D10SDKLayers.dll loaded during my DX11 game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934374/why-is-d3d10sdklayers-dll-loaded-during-my-dx11-game) .

ClipCursor will fail ever time the situations i describe in that question arise. Also, in response to my 2nd question, the window size is incorrect because of the situation I describe in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately according to a comment on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip.aspx#1) (by a user) it appears that this does not work for multimonitor setups. You may want to develop a method that will reposition the mouse when it goes off screen, turns off the rendring for it, then turn it back on when you move the cursor back to the window (to detect if the mouse moves off the window or not, there is windows messages for that).

Comment: I am hesitant to accept this, because some of the DX11 samples I've seen correctly clip the cursor even with multiple monitors. Additionally, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383(v=vs.85).aspx does not say it isn't supported on multimon.

Comment: The DX11 samples use an additional api (DXUT) that may be clipping the cursor with something besides just ClipCursor. Perhaps there is something additional they are doing?

Comment: no, I am doing the same thing DXUT is doing. thanks for the help, I found out that this is part of a different problem I am having that is also on stackoverflow @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934374/why-is-d3d10sdklayers-dll-loaded-during-my-dx11-game. I will be deleting this question since it has nothing to do with ClipCursor - ClipCursor works just fine.

Comment: If the solution is relevant, perhaps you could post the solution here and accept your own answer. That way it would benefit others.